# How does one spawn a wither skeleton with a name using a command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In a world I am creating, I would like to summon a named Wither Skeleton. However, I don't know the commands to use.

Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 4):

Do `/summon Skeleton ~ ~ ~ {SkeletonType:1, CustomName:"namehere", CustomNameVisible:1}`

This will summon a Wither Skeleton right at your feet. Put this in a command block if it's too long for the chat.

Replace `namehere` with whatever name you want.